# Decreasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

Given that $0 < a < b < 1$, I need to establish that the sequence $(U\;n=b^n - a^n)$ is decreasing versus $n$.

So I take the corresponding real function $(f\;x=b^x - a^x)$, then I compute its derivative like that:
$f'(x)=b^x\times (ln\:b) - a^x\times (ln\:a)$.
Normally I should prove that $f'(x) < 0$ to show that $f$ is decreasing.
Is it right? However, I fail to establish directly from the assumptions the sign of $f'$!
Am I missing something? or there is may be another way to prove that $f' < 0$.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about rewriting $$ U(n)= b^n-a^n = b^n \left(1-\left(\frac ab \right)^n \right) $$ 
Step 1: Here $ \left(\frac ab \right)^n $ goes to zero when $n$ goest to $\infty$ because $ b\gt a$ (by definition of the problem).

Step 2: Then the whole parenthese goes to $1$.

Step 3: After that, the cofactor $b^n$ of the parenthese goes to zero because also $b\lt1$ (by definition of the problem).

Comment: Then, if $U(n) \to 0$, by which theorem please can I say that it is decreasing? Thanks

Comment: @Mai: ??? I've included the reference to $U(n)$. So perhaps it is clearer now?

Comment: Sorry, but not really? I need to establish that $U(n)$ is decreasing.

Comment: Hmm. The only theorem you need is, that for a number $x$ between *0* and *1*, such that $0 \lt x \lt 1$ , any positive power $x^p$ is smaller than $x$ if $p \gt 1$. (I didn't get the idea that you needed an explicite theorem for this). But the three explanation-steps in my answer are only using this theorem. I hope I could make things clearer?

Answer (score 1):

The exponential and logarithm  are both increasing so $b^x>a^x$ and $ln(b)>ln(a)$, also note that $0>ln(b)> ln(a)$ (as $0<a<b<1$). It follows that  $b^x ln(b) < a^x ln(a)$, which gives us the desire conclusion.

Comment: Sorry, but in general, do you have if $0 < x1 < x2$, $y1 < y2 < 0$, then $x2\times y2 < x1 \times y1$?

Comment: @Mai09el $|b^xln b|>|a^x ln a|$ but both are negative so you get the desired inequality.

Comment: Please, I'm a little bit confused, but I don't see how this inequality can be so obvious, as $\left | ln\:b \right | < \left | ln \:a \right |$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The statement to be proven has to be weakened. If, e.g., $a=0.5$ and $b=0.99$, then the sequence $s_n:=b^n-a^n$ starts in increasing mode. Therefore we only can prove that the sequence $(s_n)_{n\geq1}$ is *eventually decreasing*.

Assume $n>{b\over 1-b}$. Then $n>(n+1) b$ and therefore
$$n x^{n-1}>(n+1) b x^{n-1}\geq (n+1) x^n\qquad(a\leq x\leq b)\ .$$
It follows that
$$s_n=\int_a^b n x^{n-1}\ dx>\int_a^b (n+1)x^n\ dx=s_{n+1}\ .$$